# Doctrine DQL: condition on left join

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have a one to many schema: Desk has many Bills.
Is it possible to fetch all Desk records with some Bill records.

I am trying to do this:

```
//DeskTable.class.php

public function getDesks()
{
    $q = $this->createQuery('d')
      ->leftJoin('d.Bills b')
      ->where('b.is_open = ?', true);

    return $q->execute();
}
```

But I get a list of Desks that have open Bills, whereas I need all Desks. Is this possible?

I am totally not a sql kind of kid, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Doctrine's `WITH` keyword ([docs here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language/hu#join-syntax%3awith-keyword)):

```
$q = $this->createQuery('d')
  ->leftJoin('d.Bills b WITH b.is_open = ?', true)

return $q->execute();
```

Comment: Ah, I knew it would be easy.. Thank you!